# How to do nullable control the most effective?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

To .cshtml coming price null and returned error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 @foreach (var product in ProductsModel)
 {
   <tr>
      <td>product.ProductName</td>
      <td>product.Category</td>
      <td>product.Price.Value.ToString("N2")</td>
   </tr>
  }
```

I solved this problem like this;

```
<td>product.Price != null ? product.Price.Value.ToString("N2") : ""</td>
```

but I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1: **make sure price is never null**:

```
class Product{
    ...
    public decimal Price { get; set; } = 0;
    ....
}
```

Way 2: **syntactic sugar**:

```cs
<td>product.Price?.Value.ToString("N2") ?? ""</td>
```

Comment: I've tried 2 ways, but this is the result;
'Nullable object must have a value.'

Comment: @erkan what is the type of `Price`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use struct instead of classes for `ProductsModel` only if `ProductsModel` is light.
If `price` is a number, c# will auto initialize it to `0` inside a struct.
Moreover, you can default initialize your variable as;

```
    string price = "";
```

in a constructor or via default initializers in C# if the price is not context-dependent.